# Multiply numbers represented as Linked List

Tags: java, loops, recursion, linked-list, biginteger

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while, now, but none of my approaches have worked so far.

You're given two linked lists that represents big numbers, where the head of the lists represent the least significant digit.
Return a new list which stores the result of the multiplication of the two lists.

I've tried an algorithm that worked for the first list being a single number, but not more than that.

1. Initialize a new list.
2. Initialize a carry.
3. While node 1 is not null:
4. While node 2 is not null:
5. If node 3's next is not null, add it's value to the carry;
6. Set node 3's next as node 1 * node 2's value + carry.
7. Set node 2 as it's next, set node 3 as it's next.
8. End while set at section 4
9. Set node 1 as node 1's next.
10. End while set at section 3.
11. Return list set at section 1.

This obviously has problems. I've also tried to set a "powCounter" for each iteration of the first loop, and multiply the value by 10 to the power of powCounter.
But this didn't work either.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: If you've been trying to solve this problem for a while, now, then you must have some code. Show that code in the question. Right now this question looks like a write-my-code-for-me request, and that's not what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/202153)

Comment: Hi @Andreas, I'm sorry to have given that impression. I do have the code written, with the algorithm I described. I just thought it would be easier to describe it, as I used a function, an overload to said function, and another function to be called for in recursion. I felt like the explanation of the algorithm would be more intuitive and faster to read. I would like to apologize again for not making this more clear.

Comment: No, never just explain the code, *show* the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like you would on paper.

Presumably, before tasking you to write `multiply(a, b)`, they would have already had you write `add(a, b)`, right? So use that.

You said you already wrote logic for multiply with a single digit, so let calls that `multiplySingle(a, digit)`.

You need one more helper method, e.g. `shiftLeft(a, n)`, which adds `n` 0's to the end of the number, i.e. to the beginning of the list. E.g. `shiftLeft([4,3,2,1], 2)` should return `[0,0,4,3,2,1]`, meaning `1234 * 10² = 123400`.

So, on paper you would multiply `123` with `456` like this:

```java
123 * 456
    45600  =  1 * 456 * 100  =  shiftLeft(multiplySingle([6,5,4], 1), 2)
     9120  =  2 * 456 * 10   =  shiftLeft(multiplySingle([6,5,4], 2), 1)
     1368  =  3 * 456 * 1    =  shiftLeft(multiplySingle([6,5,4], 3), 0)
    =====
    56088  = 45600 + 9120 + 1368  =  add(add([0,0,6,5,4], [0,2,1,9]), [8,6,3,1])
```

Good luck writing the code for that.

---

*FYI:* The idea for a `shiftLeft()` method is based on similar methods in the built-in `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` classes.

- [`BigInteger shiftLeft(int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#shiftLeft-int-)

  > Returns a `BigInteger` whose value is `(this << n)`. The shift distance, `n`, may be negative, in which case this method performs a right shift. (Computes **`floor(this * 2ⁿ)`**.)
- [`BigDecimal movePointRight(int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#movePointRight-int-)

  > Returns a `BigDecimal` which is equivalent to this one with the decimal point moved `n` places to the right. If `n` is non-negative, the call merely subtracts `n` from the scale. If `n` is negative, the call is equivalent to `movePointLeft(-n)`. The `BigDecimal` returned by this call has value **`(this × 10ⁿ)`** and scale `max(this.scale()-n, 0)`.

Comment: Thank you, I just implemented the ShiftLeft and it's working like clockwork.
Appreciate your thorough answer, Andreas.